# How do I keep global state, not using dynamic scope, in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: global-variables, elisp

I know I can create a global variable with dynamic binding with `defvar`. However, using dynamic scope  is not recommended these days.
I also know I can create a customization variable with defcustom.

What if I am writing a program that needs to store some internal state (the program uses lexical binding)? Do I simply do an initial `setq` when the package is loaded, and that's all? What would be the recommended way, currently?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> However, using dynamic scope is not recommended these days.

Not true.

Dynamic scope is not recommended for variables which *only need* to be lexically-scoped.  That is all.

If there is any need (or potential) for the variable to be accessed or set outside of the lexical scope, then that variable should be dynamic.

Using `defvar` or `defcustom` is absolutely correct for the uses you're talking about.  If it's not something which users should touch, then you would use `defvar` and the double-hyphen naming scheme `PREFIX--REST-OF-NAME` for the prefix used for your library, to indicate that it's intended to be "private".

Note that there is no default 'top level' lexical environment in a library, so you can't simply `setq` a variable and have it be visible to (only) all forms in the same library.  Lexical environments are only established for "binding constructs" like `let`.  You *could* wrap your entire library in a `let` form, of course; but I've never seen anyone recommend doing that.

Comment: Thank you! I had some trouble finding the relevant discussion. Could you point me to some place where this has been discussed before? mailing lists, blogs, etc?

Comment: I don't know that it has been discussed as such -- it doesn't seem like something which was up for discussion in the first place.  Dynamic binding is absolutely crucial to Emacs, so there probably won't have been any serious conversations about authors ceasing to use dynamic variables.

Comment: See `C-h i g (elisp)Using Lexical Binding` if you haven't already.